# Use dataframe name as suffix when joining several data frames

Tags: r, join, dplyr

I need to merge several data frames with duplicated column names. I am using `dplyr::left_join`, with `purrr::reduce` to iterate the function over the files. The standard behavior of `dplyr::left_join` is to add a suffix to duplicated col names, but that doesn't help to figure out which files the variable comes from unless you have the code handy. Below is a simplified example of my situation:

```
a <- tibble(id = 1:5, var=letters[1:5])
b <- tibble(var=letters[11:15], id=1:5)
c <- tibble(id = 1:5, var=letters[16:20], var2="a")
reduce(list(a,b,c), left_join, by="id")

# A tibble: 5 x 5
     id var.x var.y var   var2 
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 a     k     p     a    
2     2 b     l     q     a    
3     3 c     m     r     a    
4     4 d     n     s     a    
5     5 e     o     t     a
```

Is there a way to use the dataframe name as suffix, and to force the suffix to **all** the duplicated columns? What I'd like to have is:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
     id var.a var.b var.c   var2 
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>
1     1 a     k     p      a    
2     2 b     l     q      a    
3     3 c     m     r      a    
4     4 d     n     s      a    
5     5 e     o     t      a
```

There a `suffix` option in `left_join`, but how can I use it within `reduce`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the suffix in left_join cannot work since it does not know which columns are unique or not unique across all input data frames when acting on only two at a time.

**1)** Instead suffix all non-by columns in all data frames prior to the joins.  The by = "id" in the left_join line could be omitted since it will default to that.

At the end we remove the suffix on columns which uniquely appear without the suffix; however, that may not really be needed in which case omit the rmSuffix (which removes any suffix) and uniq_stem (which returns only those components of its vector argument whose stem is unique) and the rename_with line at the end of the  pipeline.

This approach would likely be ok if you don't need the final rename_with and associated functions it uses since then it is quite simple; otherwise, probably best to go with (2) to avoid certain edge cases that remain in (1) and the ugliness of setting the column names prior to the left_join only to have to fix them up again after the left_join.

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)

rmSuffix <- function(x) sub("\\.[^.]*", "", x)
uniq_stem <- function(x) x[ave(x, rmSuffix(x), FUN = length) == 1]

lst(a, b, c) %>%
  map2(names(.), ~ rename_with(.x, function(x) paste(x, .y, sep = "."), -id)) %>%
  reduce(left_join, by = "id") %>%
  rename_with(rmSuffix, .cols = uniq_stem(names(.)))
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 5 x 5
     id var.a var.b var.c var2 
  <int> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1     1 a     k     p     a    
2     2 b     l     q     a    
3     3 c     m     r     a    
4     4 d     n     s     a    
5     5 e     o     t     a
```

**2)**  A second approach is to entirely process the list prior to the left_join's.  This eliminates all regular expressions and problems associated with fixing up the initial renames in (1).  add_suffix has data.frame and list methods. In the latter case the list must be a named list of data frames and exclude is a vector of column names for which a suffix is not to be added in addition to uniquely occurring column names in the data frames of the list.

```
add_suffix <- function(x, ...) UseMethod("add_suffix")

add_suffix.data.frame <- function(x, suffix, exclude = NULL, ...) {
  ok <- !names(x) %in% exclude
  names(x)[ok] <- paste(names(x)[ok], suffix, sep = ".")
  x
}

add_suffix.list <- function(x, exclude = NULL, ...) {
  nms <- unlist(lapply(x, names))
  exclude2 <- unname(c(nms[ave(nms, nms, FUN = length) == 1], exclude))
  Map(add_suffix, x, names(x), MoreArgs = list(exclude = exclude2))
}


lst(a, b, c) %>%
  add_suffix(exclude = "id") %>%
  reduce(left_join, by = "id")
```

Comment: Thanks, but this seems to work only if the dataframes have the same numbers of columns and columns have the same position, which is the case in my simplified example, but not in the actual situation. I modified the example to make this more clear and to ask for a general solution.

Comment: Have changed to reflect change in the question's example.

Comment: Great! As a last polish: this code would not work as intended if the variable names include a point, I think that the regex expression in the "stemify" function should be `\.[^\.]*$`. If that's correct, would you mind to add it to your code so I can accept the solution?