# Select df and variables from a list with a reference df for variables selection

Tags: r, list, select, tidyverse, purrr

I've got a list of df , with different variables.

At the end, I want to get a synthesis dataframe, from a sub-selection of dataframes and variables, joined into one.
I have another df with the list of variables of interest and the corresponding tables.

Of course, to make the selection on a simple df, it would be enough to make a select(colnames(.) %in% VarSel$Var) and do it for all df and then make join...
but, for now, I can't do that directly in purrr on the list of selected df.

Do you have any idea how to do this properly?

```r
# reprex

## a list of df 

list_df <- list(A = data.frame(ID = letters[1:10],
                               Var1 = rnorm(10),
                               Var2 = rnorm(10),
                                Var3 = rnorm(10)),
                B = data.frame(ID = letters[1:10],
                               Var1 = rnorm(10),
                               VarY = rnorm(10),
                               VarX = rnorm(10)),
                D = data.frame(ID = letters[5:14],
                               Var1 = rnorm(10),
                               VarZ = rnorm(10),
                               Var3 = rnorm(10)),
                E = data.frame(ID = letters[3:12],
                               Var1 = rnorm(10),
                               VarK = rnorm(10),
                               Var3 = rnorm(10)))

## a df for variables & df selection 

VarSel <- data.frame(Var = c("ID", "VarZ", "Var3", "Var3", "VarK"),
                     Df = c("all", "D", "A", "D", "E"))



# the 3 operations that I want to perform (I simply managed the first one)

list_df %>% 
  keep(names(.) %in% unique(VarSel$Df))# keep only df named in VarSel 
                                       # then select matching variable names for thoses DF (not forgetting the ID one) 
                                       # finally produce a synthesis Df joining A & D and variables of interest (ID, VarZ, Var3, Var3)

# desired output 
output <- full_join(list_df[["A"]], list_df[["D"]], by = "ID") %>%
full_join(.,list_df[["E"]], by= "ID") %>% 
select(ID, VarZ, Var3_A = Var3.x, Var3_D = Var3.y, VarK)
```

Comment: I try several ways to use select and %in% functions in a map() but i didn't suceed...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could utilize this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66461873/use-dataframe-name-as-suffix-when-joining-several-data-frames) for using the right dataframes names as suffix while joining, e.g.

```
rmSuffix <- function(x) sub("\\_[^.]*", "", x)
uniq_stem <- function(x) x[ave(x, rmSuffix(x), FUN = length) == 1]


keep_list <- list_df %>% 
  keep(names(.) %in% unique(VarSel$Df)) 


map2(keep_list, names(keep_list), ~ rename_with(.x, function(x) paste(x, .y, sep = "_"), -ID)) |> 
  reduce(full_join, by = "ID") |> 
  select(contains(VarSel$Var)) %>% 
  rename_with(rmSuffix, .cols = uniq_stem(names(.))) |> 
  select(-Var3_E)
```

**Output:**

```
   ID       VarZ      Var3_A      Var3_D         VarK
1   a         NA  0.07013416          NA           NA
2   b         NA -0.20262710          NA           NA
3   c         NA -0.12263637          NA  0.905559370
4   d         NA -0.24115062          NA -0.220275164
5   e -0.3153504 -1.71601081  0.39305203  0.199025384
6   f  1.0408308  1.63679816  0.52372235  0.977966335
7   g -1.2133189 -1.64706077  0.04712189 -1.415394796
8   h -1.4864888  1.08853254 -0.67286743 -0.920097871
9   i  1.3551027  0.57154103 -0.97045208 -0.750717887
10  j  1.1669465  1.18983409 -0.42142208 -0.873252568
11  k  0.1631669          NA -1.01488606 -0.674366819
12  l  0.2537215          NA -0.13341806  0.005410001
13  m -1.0206924          NA  0.75391722           NA
14  n -0.2618105          NA -0.14547705           NA
```

Comment: thanks a lot ! finally, on my real dataset, I didn't apply the regex functions for the suffixes, because in order to avoid any ambiguity, I found it good to keep the original file name for each variable.       
`output <- map2( .x = keep_list, .y = names(keep_list),  ~ rename_with(.x, function(x) paste(x, .y, sep = "_"),  -ID) ) %>%  reduce(full_join, by = "ID") %>% select(contains(paste(VarSel$Nom, VarSel$Df, sep = "_")))`

Answer (score 1):

You could do:

```r
library(purrr)
map2_dfc(list_df[VarSel$Df], VarSel$Var, ~ .x[.y])

#    ID       VarZ   Var3...3    Var3...4
# 1   a  1.0215807 -0.9307522 -0.79314560
# 2   b -1.3861810 -1.1376876 -3.06921836
# 3   c  0.4661697  0.3690057 -0.08778707
# 4   d  0.1365207  0.5290638  0.86164346
# 5   e  0.5498877 -0.6208638 -2.22677452
# 6   f  0.4925813 -1.3938548  0.21014465
# 7   g  0.3675358  0.8269150 -1.71422099
# 8   h  0.4576200  0.1554632 -1.80290292
# 9   i  0.5560993  0.6597010 -1.43455363
# 10  j  0.2121097 -0.5935487 -1.42085047
```

---

Note that I changed your VarSel a bit to avoid `"all"` which would not be recognized. Since they're all identical, I picked "A".

```r
VarSel <- data.frame(Var = c("ID", "VarZ", "Var3", "Var3"),
                     Df = c("A", "D", "A", "D"))
```

---

To get the exact correct output, you could create a vector of newnames dynamically, and then use `pmap`:

```r
newnames <- ifelse(duplicated(VarSel$Var) | duplicated(VarSel$Var, fromLast = TRUE), 
                   paste0(VarSel$Var, "_", VarSel$Df), VarSel$Var)
pmap_dfc(list(list_df[VarSel$Df], VarSel$Var, newnames), ~ set_names(..1[..2], ..3))

#    ID       VarZ     Var3_A      Var3_D
# 1   a  1.0215807 -0.9307522 -0.79314560
# 2   b -1.3861810 -1.1376876 -3.06921836
# 3   c  0.4661697  0.3690057 -0.08778707
# 4   d  0.1365207  0.5290638  0.86164346
# 5   e  0.5498877 -0.6208638 -2.22677452
# 6   f  0.4925813 -1.3938548  0.21014465
# 7   g  0.3675358  0.8269150 -1.71422099
# 8   h  0.4576200  0.1554632 -1.80290292
# 9   i  0.5560993  0.6597010 -1.43455363
# 10  j  0.2121097 -0.5935487 -1.42085047
```

Comment: Thank you, it's a nice solution. I'm aware of the "all" issue, that's why I first tried something with %in% operator to make sure ID is recovered from all selected df

Comment: sorry, I've just realized that my reprex (input and output) was misleading. I edited, I actually want to perform a join.